# Is there a way to use Ajax in google app script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I register the records on spreadsheet, I want to load them on the html interface automatically without refreshing the page. Is there anyway to use Ajax, or to refresh part of the html , or any other method ? Is there any example ?

Please help.
Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Check out [this.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: And [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345467/communicate-between-sidebar-and-modal-dialogue-box-in-google-script/42357966#42357966) to.