# Embedding editable spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, contenteditable, embedding

I'm trying to make something like a calculator using google spreadsheet and put this in iframe on my website. Problem i'm having is that embedded code make spreadsheet un-editable. I know how to resize etc. but I don't know how to make my sheet editable. Any help will be appreciated...
Andre

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example of a dialog communicating with the server.  The html dialog is probably the place that you will want to create your calculator.  You can use standard html,javascript,jquery and other things.  And if you wish to call any Google Script all you have to do is call it with `google.script.run.yourfunctionname();`

The other advantage to doing it this way is that you can probably deploy it as a web app when your through.  In the meantime during development you have much greater access to the user interface as a dialog or a sidebar.  During this process you'll have the opportunity to get to know your debugger and the chrome developer tools which is somewhat documented in [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting).

Checkout out think [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) for learning about how to communicate with the server and how to use the call back functions.

The example is already on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42357966/7215091).

Comment: Thanks Cooper!
I'm very sorry but i do not know how to write a HTML code. I'm using "Publish to the web" option on my spreadsheet and i'm trying to edit the code. I did figure-out how to remove header, footer etc but i do not know how to make my spreadsheet editable! I know i have add code like - edit?usp=sharing - but I don't know the syntax...
Thanks
Andre

Comment: Oh if your using Publish to the Web then your basically stuck with a view only file.  Here's a little [blurb about it](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). I don't like tell anyone they can't do something but I'm pretty sure that there are a lot easier ways to do it.  Unfortunately, there is the Google Apps Script learning curve.  But check the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/), I think it's pretty good.  But yes it's not a trivial read.