# How to send data from modal dialog to sidebar (and vice versa) when event occurs (button clicked)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sidebar with a simple form with a dropdown that selects some categories of the entries. There's a button beside it for the user to add a new category. This button shows a modal dialog and in this dialog there's an input box for the user to input the new category name and an "Add New" button that will send the new item back to the sidebar. I would like for the respective dropdown to have the new category included among its options plus its text to be already populated with the new name.

All I could think so far was to use the `localStorage` but I then I don't know how to trigger updates to the dropdown on the sidebar (or any other element) when the button is pressed and the dialog is closed with a new value submitted. I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58179202/how-to-show-hide-loading-spinner-in-addon-sidebar-while-google-picker-dialog-is/58186493#58186493) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263889/how-to-update-html-in-sidebar-template-from-modal-dialog-template-with-javascrip/41265164#41265164) but I couldn't really get it to work to my case.

I have supressed the `Code.gs` pieces because they work just fine and are not relevant.

#### `sidebar.html`

```html
<script>
  document.getElementById("btn-add-category").addEventListener("click", goToAddNewItem);

  function goToAddNewItem(){
    google.script.run.loadNewItemForm();
  }
      
  (async () => {
    //After modal dialog has finished, receiver will be resolved
    let receiver = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    window.modalDone = res;
    });
    var message = await receiver;
    
    document.getElementById("category-sidebar").value = message
  })();
</script>
```

#### `modal.html`

This is the `html` file of the modal dialog:

```html
<body>
  <div class="form-group" id="input-category">
    <label for="category">Category:</label>
    <div class="input-group input-line">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="category">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button id="btn-add-new" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Add New</button>
  </div>

  <script>

    function findSideBar(limit) {
      let f = window.top.frames;

      for (let i = 0; i < limit; ++i) {
        try {
          if (
            f[i] /*/iframedAppPanel*/ &&
            f[i].length &&
            f[i][0] && //#sandboxFrame
            f[i][0][0] && //#userHtmlFrame
            window !== f[i][0][0] //!== self
          ) {
            console.info('Sidebar found ');
            var sidebar = f[i][0][0];
            sidebar.modalDone(document.getElementById("category").value);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
          continue;
        }
      }
    };

    function afterAddNewClicked(){
      findSideBar(10);
      google.script.host.close();
    }

    document.getElementById("btn-add-new").addEventListener("click", afterAddNewClicked);

  </script>
</body>
```

#### EDIT:

`modal.html` now has the function `findSidebar`

Comment: Where is your findSideBar function ?

Comment: @TheMaster I didn't implement it. Using that function is the only way to communicate between sidebar and dialog?

Comment: As my previous answer states, that is one of the way, but provides the best access.

Comment: @TheMaster alright, I'm just a bit confused on how to set the submitted value to the dropdown after the button is clicked in the modal dialog.

Comment: @TheMaster I edited the post with the current code I have. In the modal.html I added the findSidebar function and the line to send it back to the sidebar modalDone but I still don't get the dropdown to update

Comment: Need logs and debugging effort. Start by looking into the browser devtools console.

Comment: Since you can just send anything to sidebar or a dialog. You will need to have both sidebar and dialog polling for information.  So it makes sense to have a polling manager on the server directing traffic to  and from each dialog.

Comment: `label` doesn't have a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
sidebar.modalDone = document.getElementById("category").value
```

`res` or `modalDone` needs to be called. Just assigning a value won't work. Try

```
sidebar.modalDone(document.getElementById("category").value);
```

Comment: I have tried both options and it seems that the correct element is caught but its value is not set somehow

Comment: All the corresponding code is in the post already with the exception of other elements on the page.

Comment: @everspader That's the thing. I or anyone else cannot verify that the problem even exists without a "reproducible" example, which includes elements/html and all other source. The code also needs to be "minimal". Nobody has to mess with your actual  source. You need to provide code that reliably reproduces the exact problem. To do this, follow [mcve]. Step1  is "Starting from scratch": Then keep adding 1 by 1 until the problem appears and then you'll have a mcve. See [mcve]- It's the art of debugging: value what is written and follow it to the dot.