# GAS PropertiesService to Save and Return Sort Order

Tags: jquery-ui, google-apps-script, web-applications

**QUESTION**

How can I use `PropertiesService` to store an array from `index.html`, send the array to `code.gs`, and return the array in index.html?

**SPECIFIC CASE**

In a Google Web App, I have a group of sortable lists (made using JQuery UI Sortable). I want to save the most recent order/position of each `li`. I'm attempting to have that order/position "persist" when the page is refreshed or closed.

**EXAMPLE**

[If you see the default Sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default), you could change the order of the items. If you refreshed the page, or closed it and return, the items would be in their original order.

**WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE**

I am able to get the array to show up in the console, but I don't know how to get it back to code.gs. I think I am now, but I'm not sure. Beyond that, I don't know how to "read" that `PropertiesService` so that the array is returned to `index.html`. I'm not really sure what I'm doing so if someone could slow walk me it would be appreciated!

**ALTERNATIVES**

I also looked into writing directly to the spreadsheet where the values originate. I'm not really sure how to do that either. I made some attempts, and was able to get "undefined" as a value in a spreadsheet cell.

**FULL CODE** (note: the list items are formed using an array, so they will not show up here): https://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/Lmcjzho2/1/

**PARTIAL CODE**

code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function webAppTest() {
  getTeamArray();
}

function getTeamArray() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TEST');
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1000, 1);
  var values = range.getValues();

  var teamsArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
    teamsArray.push(values[i][0]);
  }

  var uniqueArray = [];

  uniqueArray.push(teamsArray[0]);

  for (var i in teamsArray) {
    if ((uniqueArray[uniqueArray.length - 1] != teamsArray[i]) && (teamsArray[i] !== "")) {
      uniqueArray.push(teamsArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return uniqueArray;
}

function savePositions(myProperty, positions) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("myProperty", JSON.stringify(positions));
};

function getPositions() {
  var returnedObj = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
};
```

index.html

```
  <body>



    <div id="myList" class="connectedSortable">MY LIST</div>

    <table id=table1>
      <div id="team1">
        <p>TEAM 1</p>
        <br>
        <div id="group" v>SELECTED</div>
        <ul id="team1s" name='team1s' class="connectedSortable"></ul>
        <div id="group">ALTERNATE</div>
        <ul id="team1a" name='team1a' class="connectedSortable"></ul>
      </div>
    </table>

    <table id=table2>
      <div id="team2">
        <p>TEAM 2</p>
        <br>
        <div id="group" v>SELECTED</div>
        <ul id="team2s" name='team2s' class="connectedSortable"></ul>
        <div id="group">ALTERNATE</div>
        <ul id="team2a" name='team2a' class="connectedSortable"></ul>
      </div>
    </table>

    <table id=table3>
      <div id="team3">
        <p>TEAM 3</p>
        <br>
        <div id="group" v>SELECTED</div>
        <ul id="team3s" name='team3s' class="connectedSortable"></ul>
        <div id="group">ALTERNATE</div>
        <ul id="team3a" name='team3a' class="connectedSortable"></ul>
      </div>
    </table>

    <table id=table4>
      <div id="team4">
        <p>TEAM 4</p>
        <br>
        <div id="group" v>SELECTED</div>
        <ul id="team4s" name='team4s' class="connectedSortable"></ul>
        <div id="group">ALTERNATE</div>
        <ul id="team4a" name='team4a' class="connectedSortable"></ul>
      </div>
    </table>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionsList)
          .getTeamArray();
      });


      function buildOptionsList(uniqueArray) {
        var div = document.getElementById('myList');
        for (var i = 0; i < uniqueArray.length; i++) {
          var ul = document.createElement('ul');
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          var cLass = li.setAttribute('class', 'ui-state-default');
          var iD = li.setAttribute('id', uniqueArray[i]);


          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(uniqueArray[i]));
          div.appendChild(ul);
          div.appendChild(li);
        }
      }

      $(function() {
        $("#myList, #team1s, #team1a, #team2s, #team2a, #team2s, #team3s, #team3a, #team4s, #team4a").sortable({
          connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
          update: function(event, ui) {
            var changedList = this.id;
            var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
            var positions = order.join(';');

            console.log({
              id: changedList,
              positions: positions

            });

            //Instead of using JSON to save, can I use the spreadsheet itself to save the positions and then pull it from there as I did with "buildOptionsList" above?

            function saveList() {
              google.script.run.savePositions("myProperty", JSON.stringify(positions));

              JSON.parse("myProperty");
            }
          }
        })
      });


      $(function getPositions(event, ui) {
        var changedList = this.id;
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        var positions = order.join(';');

        console.log({
          id: changedList,
          positions: positions
        });

      });

    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked [Client to Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using google.script.run simple example:

```
<script>
function sendStringToServer() {
  var string=$('#text1').val();
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(s){
    alert(s);
  })
  .saveString(string);
}
</script>
```

Google Script:

```
function myFunction() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('MyString', string);
  return "String was saved in Service";
}
```

- [Client to Server Communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: Ok i was able to edit that so it looks like this: https://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/2fedgtxv/7/

How do I return that list to index.html? Do I need to `getProperty("MyString")` in the same GS function, or create an entirely new set of functions in `index.html` and `code.gs`?

Comment: Your HTML file has to request it by using google.script.run with a success handler and the Google script on the server has to return it

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to just use the browser's [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) client side.

```
localStorage.setItem('id', positions); //Store positions in users browser
localStorage.getItem('id'); //Retrieve the stored positions later
```

#### Notes:

- For this to work, the url(`document.domain` of the iframe="*.googleusercontent.com") from which your script is deployed must remain constant. During my brief testing, it was constant even when changing from `/dev` to `/exec` of the parent(script.google.com) and even during version update. But there's no official reference.
- This solution is better than properties service, if you have multiple users, as each one will have their own data stored in their own browsers and there are no server calls during each change.

Comment: I gave it a go but it doesn't seem to work as intended. Do you mind giving this a look? https://jsfiddle.net/31fh62sq/1/

Comment: @N.O.Davis Can you explain what doesn't work? I believe that `google` will be undefined and therefore a fiddle won't pin the problem or do any help. To retrieve positions, `var retrievedPositions=localStorage.getItem('id')` should retrieve it from the browser.

Comment: I know the fiddle won't have all the google connections, but I just meant the actual code. When i refreshed the page, everything reverted back to it's original state.

Comment: @N.O That's because you aren't doing Anything with the retrieved positions. `onload`> check the localStorage for positions>if present, order the elements accordingly, else load the default view.

Comment: Good idea.  I didn't know that.  Thanks