# Navigating embedded Google Apps Script iFrame from the parent

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe, web-applications

I have a multi-page Web App. I want after login, a user sees the list of his teammate and marks their attendance status. My issue is I can't show that in an iFrame rather than google script original one.

For instance, I wanted to iFrame it to my own web page. it is two days I can't overcome this issue, I read lots of posts in this regard and also tried another app from scratch, but no luck yet.

For clarification, I am redirecting the user inside the frame using render function. So as @theMaster mentioned it is not a multi-page Web App.

here is my doGet and Render functions:

```
function doGet(e){
    // Logger.log(e);
    Route.path("login",loadLogin);  
    Route.path("admin",loadAdmin);  
    Route.path("view",loadView);
    Route.path("form",loadForm);
if (e.parameters.id){
  LastID=e.parameters.id[0]; 
}
if (e.parameters.t){
  curT=e.parameters.t[0]; 
}  
if (Route[e.parameters.v]) {
  return Route[e.parameters.v]();
} else {
  return render('W-home');
  }    
}

function render(file, argObject){
    var page = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(file);
    if (argObject){
        var keys = Object.keys(argObject);
        keys.forEach(function (k){
        page[k]=argObject[k];
        });
    }
    var evalPage =page.evaluate();
    // if (!xFrame){return evalPage;};
    return evalPage.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

I can go from home page to login page, but after that, even it doesn't let me go to google. In some cases also just returns a blank page inside the frame.

Here is my sample code for the client-side JavaScript.

```
function goToForm(EmpNo) {
  var link = "<?!=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()?>" + "?v=form&id=" + EmpNo[1] + "&t=" + EmpNo[2];
  location.href = link;
  // I tried different way to see if i can conqure this! 
  // if (clickBTN= 'a') {
  //   window.open(link, "_self");
  // } if (clickBTN= 'b') {
  //   location.href=link;
  // } if (clickBTN= 'c') {
  //   openNewURLInTheSameWindow(link);
  // }          
}
```

I also have two global variables `xFrame` to set  XframeOptionsMode to `allowAll` or not and `base` to switch base target on the HTM pages to "_top" or "_self".

Comment: After a bit of testing, I believe `window.postMessage()` is the only way.

Comment: @TheMaster I will check that and let you know. I am not familiar with this ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Issue:

You can try

```
window.top.location = link;
```

It'll load the link in the top frame. If you are framing the web-app itself in your website, then you should use

```
window.parent.parent.location = link;
```

But this won't work because the sandbox prevents navigating other frames in the document. `sandbox="allow-top-navigation"` only allows top frame navigation and not the intermediate frames. Since the top frame is your site and not `script.google.com`, it can't be navigated and you'll get the error

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL `https://myexamplesite.com`... from frame with URL https://*.googleusercontent.com/... The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors.

#### Solution:

- Use `window.postMessage()`

```
  
==================
|Your site       |<-myexamplesite.com [TOP#0]
|                |
| =============  |
| |GASWebApp  |<-|--script.google.com[Frame#1]
| |           |  |
| |=========  |  |
| ||SandBox|  |  |
| ||User   |<-|--|-- Where your html code is
| ||Frame  |  |  |  (*.googleusercontent.com) 
| |=========  |  |   [Frame#2 and #3(Double nested iframe)]
| |           |  |
| =============  |
|                |
|                |
|                |
==================
```

#### Snippet:

*Sandboxed Html:*

```html
<script>
if(window.parent.parent !== window.top){ //if #1 !== top
  //Framed in a another web-app
  //TODO Use proper target origin instead of *
   window.parent.parent.parent.postMessage("[FRAME#1_LINK_TO_CHANGE]","*");//Post to #0
}
</script>
```

*Top frame*(#0):

```html
<!-- Frame the Apps script Web-App Frame#1-->
<iframe
  src="https://script.google.com/macros/s/[SCRIPT_DEPLOYMENT_ID]/exec"
  >Loading...</iframe
>
<script type="text/javascript">
  const handleMessage = function(event) {
    if (
      event.origin !==
      'https://[SCRIPT_ORIGIN]script.googleusercontent.com'
    ) {
      alert('Origin Disallowed');
      return;
    }
      //TODO Check syntax of event.data before changing iframe src
      document.querySelector('iframe').src = event.data; //Change #1 Link
  };
  window.addEventListener('message', handleMessage);
</script>
```

#### References:

- [Basic GAS webapp structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551837)
- [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)
- [iFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: hi, It jumps out of frame and shows the Google notes on top!
but it at least returns something. the other three approach is giving me a blank page!

Comment: @Mahhdy You need to remove the third line: `location.href=link;`

Comment: this was the exact code I had. 
         ` function goToForm(EmpNo){
            var link = "<?=ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()?>"+"?v=form&id="+EmpNo[1]+"&t="+EmpNo[2];
            window.top.location =link;`

Comment: what do you mean by Top frame? I want the url in my iframe, inside the page not on the parent page. Are we align?

Comment: @Mahh `I want the url in my iframe, inside the page not on the parent page`. I see. So, you don't want a multi page application. But a single page application simulating multiple pages. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54989042). I think it can help.

Comment: @Mahh Are you using another iframe to load the web-app?  The web-app itself loads inside a iframe. In that case, you should use `window.parent.location = link;`

Comment: by using `windows.parent.location` this error showed up:  userCodeAppPanel:83 Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'https://n-****-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel' from frame with URL 'https://n-2*****-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'. The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors.

Comment: @Mah Did you remove location.href=link;. You seem to have a nested iframe both from `*.googleusercontent.com`. If everything is written well, you should have your top frame-``Your site``> iframe>`script.google.com`>iframe-userframe-`*.googleusercontent.com`

Comment: Thanks of your note. I checked again, really frustrated! I didn't find anything! for test I am just using live server plug in of visual studio code and simple iframe inside of that! 
other funny things is when I changing the base target to `_self`, i cant check my latest code status and I have to publish each minor change to see that!

Comment: @Mahhdy Try setting target as `_parent`. View source code of your app to see the structure of iframes. Search for iframe. Also, You should publish all minor changes.

Comment: with `_parent` it will open links in a new window and shows them inside google usual page!

Comment: Note: *OP confirmed that this works, but I believe mods deleted that "Thank you! It works" comments*

Comment: seems like iframe [now have it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#september_1_2021): `the allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation attribute has been added to the sandbox` not sure if it would work without user interaction

Comment: @Kos That's kinda bad news. They removed `allow-top-navigation` and added `allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation` instead. So, what you could do previously without user activation, now you need user activation. But my script shouldn't be affected in any case - as it uses a top down approach - the external site script is the one changing the link.

Comment: @TheMaster it would be extermly helpful if you provide practical example how to make it work with the on click links.

Comment: @Abdel5 Feel free to ask a new question. But  it's simple as `button.onclick = ()=>window.parent.parent.parent.postMessage("[FRAME#1_LINK_TO_CHANGE]","*");//Post to #0`

Comment: @TheMaster: Probably you could help me with this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69992538/how-to-navigate-link-to-different-google-sites-from-an-embedded-google-app-scr