# How do I link to another page using a webapp embedded in Google Sites?

Tags: google-apps-script, iframe

Upon clicking on a link to a new page, nothing happens from the user's perspective. The console prints out the error which reads:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin
> 'https://sites.google.com' from frame with URL
> 'https://n-frzjyfhgihna65vdvol2wbbsyjjlfhey2xruiny-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'.
> The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed,
> but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or
> 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

I'm not sure how to interpret this. From what I've read, Google Sites has a security measure that prevents embedded webapps from navigating using the "_top" page. Navigating using "_blank" as my target works, but is not what I hope to accomplish. How do I overcome this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [issue with Embedding Google Apps Script in an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400233/issue-with-embedding-google-apps-script-in-an-iframe)

Comment: Please take time to read and practice the references in that question until you understand. See [ask] and [mre]. I don't think I can dumb it down more. If there's a specific thing you don't  understand, ask a new specific question(You can ask dumb question as long it is specific and you've done your homework, but I can't write a exhaustive 101 material from top to bottom in a Q/A site).

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your code but I think I know what you're referring to. I experienced the same issue and you can see how I've implemented it on my blog post here - https://script.gs/password-protected-web-app/ (I take a text input from the user and reload the page programatically)

This is what's needed on the `Code.gs` file:

```
function webAppURL(linkAddr) {
  var linkAddr = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl()
  return linkAddr
}
```

And on the webapp `*.html` page:

```
<script>
    function reload() {
        var linkAddr
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(value) {
            window.open(value, '_top');
        }).webAppURL(linkAddr);
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps and feel free to ping here in case it doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there was no change after inserting your code

Comment: What sort of code do you need? My doGet() function? The <a> tag I'm using?