# How to navigate (link) to different google sites from an embedded google app script ? Embedding navigation bar into google site

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iframe, google-sites

I am trying to embed a navigation bar written in html and served by `google script` as the `webapp` into the `google sites` page.

The navigation bar works correctly if I use in `<A>` html attribute `TARGET="_blank"`.

If I use in `<A>` html attribute `TARGET = "_top"` the link does not work (clicking it does not seem to result in any browser action).

Console error:

> Unsafe attempt to initiate navigation for frame with origin
> 'https://sites.google.com' from frame with URL
> 'https://n-rosb5zxog27qlyotjggwwxuzbuy4htzgn74xhia-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com/userCodeAppPanel'.
> The frame attempting navigation of the top-level window is sandboxed,
> but the flag of 'allow-top-navigation' or
> 'allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation' is not set.

Clicking link without any attribute results in link opening in IFRAME (part of embedded google site) with the following error message:

> sites.google.com refused to connect

I have revied the following questions:

- [Navigating embedded Google Apps Script iFrame from the parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56400233/navigating-embedded-google-apps-script-iframe-from-the-parent)
- [Where is my iframe in the published web application/sidebar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63551837/where-is-my-iframe-in-the-published-web-application-sidebar)
- [How do I link to another page using a webapp embedded in Google Sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57949796/how-do-i-link-to-another-page-using-a-webapp-embedded-in-google-sites)

but they does not seem to answer whether navigating google site is viable threw navigation bar generated in google scripts.

Example:
https://sites.google.com/mage.pl/test/strona-g%C5%82%C3%B3wna
There is no way to redirect a whole page. None of the applied options works.

**Minimal reproductive example:**

Code:

```
function doGet() {
 return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("nawigacja.html").setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Html:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>

      /* The navigation menu */
      .navbar {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #ffffff;
      }

      /* Navigation links */
      .navbar a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
      font-family: arial;
        color: #000000;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      /* The subnavigation menu */
      .subnav {
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
      }

      /* Subnav button */
      .subnav .subnavbtn {
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: #000000;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: arial;
        margin: 0;
      }

      /* Add a red background color to navigation links on hover */
      .navbar a:hover, .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
        background-color: #dedede;
      }

      /* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */
      .subnav-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #dedede;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 1;
      }

      /* Style the subnav links */
      .subnav-content a {
        float: left;
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      /* Add a grey background color on hover */
      .subnav-content a:hover {
        background-color: #eee;
        color: black;
      }

      /* When you move the mouse over the subnav container, open the subnav content */
      .subnav:hover .subnav-content {
        display: block;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Load font awesome icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- The navigation menu -->
      
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="subnav">
        <button class="subnavbtn">Menu item<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
        <div class="subnav-content">
                <a href="https://google.com" TARGET="_blank">Blank</a>
          <a href="https://sites.google.com/" TARGET="_top">Top</a>
          <a href="https://www.google.com" TARGEt="_self">Self</a>
        </div>
      </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve]? `clicking it does not seem to result in any browser action)` Was there a error thrown in the browser console?

Comment: @TheMaster: Please find attached example here: https://sites.google.com/mage.pl/test/strona-g%C5%82%C3%B3wna

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Show the error in browser console(DevTools>Console).

Comment: @TheMaster: Thanks for patience and help. The post was supplemented with console error.

Comment: How are you framing it? Provide relevant  html of Google sites. Also check the sandbox attributes of ``sandboxframe`` in devtools>Inspector, whether it has `allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for provide Google Sites example website.

I tried to look at your website and found that there are 3 nested `iframe` tag as shown in the image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uepA9.jpg

The sandbox's attributes on the top of the `iframe` on the new Google Sites are

```
allow-scripts
allow-popups
allow-forms
allow-same-origin
allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox
allow-downloads allow-modals
```

Attributes of the second nested `iframe` are

```
allow-downloads
allow-forms
allow-modals
allow-popups
allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox
allow-same-origin allow-scripts
allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation
```

And your navigation bar is located under the nested `iframe` level 3.

Maybe attributes from `iframe` first level is inherited to next nested level so when the link in navigation bar is clicked, the current tab can't be redirected to new URL with `_top` or `_parent` attribute.

To have the embedded navigation bar redirected to new URL in the current tab, it may need Google to add the sandbox attributes `allow-top-navigation-by-user-activation` in the new Google Sites.

If there are anything wrong in my post, please give me comments.

I am sorry for my not very good English.